# I accidentally removed SYSTEM group & 'Authenticated Users' group from C:\ permissions in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, permissions, systemd, user-groups

Hoping someone can help. I was following the instructions for 'Solution 6:' on this linked page in an attempt to fix a blank preview screen in the OBS Studio app

[OBS Blank Preview Screen Fixes](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-black-screen-in-obs-studio/#:%7E:text=Right%2Dclick%20anywhere%20on%20your,select%20the%20OBS%20display%20capture.)

Sadly the fix (allowing full control for the user group called 'Authenticated Users') did not work for me. So after rebooting I went back to C:\ Properties, Security tab, and unchecked all the boxes I had previously selected

I opened properties again to see if my 'unchecking everything' had stayed in place, but saw that all the checkboxes were ticked again?! (what I didn't realise at this point is the top group 'Authenticated Users' was gone and I was now on the SYSTEM group). I unchecked all the boxes again, and clicked 'Apply' just in time to see the SYSTEM group vanish before my eyes and the realization of what I'd done kicked in

I am hoping someone is going to tell me it's all going to be ok, as right now I'm too frightened to turn the laptop off in case I can never get access again. I know how to boot up into F5 and reinstall windows but if I did would the install work ok if the C:\ is locked out?

I'm very worried. This is such a dumb thing to do

Any advice appreciated, thanks

Comment: You already restarted once. Can you make a new user (Users and groups and make it a member of Administrators) and the log in as this new account?  Do things look better?

Comment: Hi @John, I haven't rebooted since unchecking all the permissions, but I can make new users groups. I didn't even try before my post as I didn't know how it was configured so why try to re-add it, but to my surprise when I typed 'SYSTEM' into the add box and clicked 'Check Names' it automatically found it & gave it an underline like when Outlook finds an email address. So I now have both groups back. I'm not sure the settings are correct but at least they are back! :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So I have managed to get both groups back, SYSTEM and 'Authenticated Users' into the permissions for the C:\ by clicking 'Add...' then in the box called 'Enter the object names to select' entering the text 'SYSTEM' then clicking 'Check Names', and repeating the same steps for the 'Authenticated Users' group

I'm not entirely sure the permission are correct. I've just ticket 'Full Control' for now and will see if I can Google the correct settings tomorrow as it's late.

Thank you John for your comment, I never would have got there otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

Restart and then make a new user (Users and groups and make it a member of Administrators) and the log in as this new account?

I think this step has helped you.